# Can I configure 'Cache' task in Azure Pipelines to only restore the cache and not the save the cache?

Tags: azure, caching, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-caching

I want to configure the 'Cache' task in Azure Pipelines to only restore the cache and not the save the cache and vice versa? Is there any workaround for this scenario?

I  read the documentation regarding caching but didn't find any solution

Comment: Hi @Vandit Agarwal, may i know if there's any update? Please check my answer below and let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to configure the 'Cache' task in Azure Pipelines to only restore the cache and not the save the cache.

The cache task is already doing this way.

It evaluates the `key` to identifier for the cache you want to restore or save, `when the key is same`, there's a `cachehit`, **it will restore the cache**, and at the end `Post-job: Cache" step`, it reports: `Cache with fingerprint xxxx already exists`, and will **skip saving**.

[image]

When `key is changed`, it will evaluate `restoreKeys` in cache task, when it's met, it's `a partial cache hit`, it will also restore the cache content, but at  end `Post-job: Cache" step`, the  `Cache with fingerprint` value is differnet, it will still save the content.
[image]

[image]

You can remove `restorekeys` in cache task, so that it will only evaluate for key value to determine restore or not.

If both `key` and `restorekeys` value is NOT met, it's `cache miss`, it will NOT restore the cache content, and save content at last `Post-job: Cache" step`.

More details please check doc [Pipeline caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops).